# Google Play console rejects my second app in Firebase same database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services

Hello I am trying to upload a second app in the same app Firebase but they always show me Error 4 in their pictures, when trying to enter with a google account[image]

Although I do not have problems to enter with the same user and account that I gave them.[image]. Of course I change the Json file to the second app , as I said I can log in without problems but they cannot.

Comment: If you want to implement Firebase authentication with Google, then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) might help. If you're using Java, you might also check [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) out.

Comment: As I said I did it correctly , the problem is that Google team cannot access.